Syntax Error: pdf2image and poppler in AWS lambda
I am attempting to run some code in a lambda in AWS but am running into an issue. The code uses the pdf2image module, which also requires the import of poppler and poppler-utils. We added these packages to layers so they are installed in the environment. However, when we attempt to run the code we get a syntax error. Python-wise, the code triggering the error does not look syntactically flawed. I am brand new to AWS and my co-worker who is handling most of the AWS side of things is brand new to Python, and neither of us are sure what is the culprit. What are we doing wrong?
Relevant portion of code
import boto3
import botocore
import poppler
import poppler-utils
import numpy as np
import json
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

Resulting error
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 4
    import poppler-utils

We did try commenting out the import poppler-utils line just to see how it changed the behavior and it gave us the following error: [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pdf2image' which does at least confirm that we absolutely do need to be importing poppler-utils in order to use pdf2image. We also checked and all of our file permissions are correct so that's not the culprit either.

poppler-utils is not a valid token for an import statement.  The "poppler-utils" pypi package does not install a module that can be imported.  The core of your error seems to be the missing pdf2image module.  How are you creating the layer with that module?
